# How do I split the htaccess domain directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two folders named domainy and domainx and they point to the same public_html folder.
I need to separate the two domains. the code below does not work properly. can be opened from one domain to another. I want to prevent this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainx.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainx.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domainx/
RewriteRule (.*) domainx/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainy.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainy.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domainy/
RewriteRule (.*) domainy/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for adding your efforts, keep it up. Could you please add URLs examples also in terms of what you are trying to achieve so that we could get a more better picture of your question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, you want to internally rewrite requests for each domain to the corresponding subdirectory. But also prevent direct access to that subdirectory. (I think it would be preferable to redirect direct requests back to the root.)

To simplify (avoid repetition) this I'll assume that the subdirectory is the same name as the domain (less the www subdomain and TLD) - as in your examples.

Try the following in the root `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect direct requests to the subdirectory back to root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(domainx|domainy)/(.*) https://www.$1.com/$2 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite domainx to the subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domainx)\.com
RewriteRule !^domainx/ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Rewrite domainy to the subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domainy)\.com
RewriteRule !^domainy/ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The first redirect directive will redirect a direct request for the subdirectory back to the root of the respective domain - based on the subdirectory being requested. For example:

- `www.domainx.com/domainx/<something>` redirects to `https://www.domainx.com/<something>`
- `www.domainy.com/domainx/<something>` redirects to `https://www.domainx.com/<something>`
- `www.domainx.com/domainy/<something>` redirects to `https://www.domainy.com/<something>`
- `www.domainy.com/domainy/<something>` redirects to `https://www.domainy.com/<something>`

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var avoids a potential redirect loop since the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is not set on the initial request and only set after the first successful rewrite.

However, this will fail if there are additional `.htaccess` files for these domains in the respective subdirectory that also contains mod_rewrite directives. In which case you would need to redirect back to root from the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory instead. If you do have additional `.htaccess` files in the subdirectory then the above directives can be simplified in other ways.

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects and change to 301 (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK - to avoid potential caching issues.

You should ideally canonicalise the non-www vs www subdomain (decide on one or the other).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer I am getting error 500.
I guess it caused a problem when domain became subdomain. my domains
 domainx.com.tr xxx.domainy.org
 How can I adapt it? I tried but did not work.

Comment: Check your server's error log for details of the 500 error. Please update your question with more accurate example URLs. I assumed both your domains are `.com` (as per your example) - and the above directives rely on this naming. " I guess it caused a problem when domain became subdomain" - not sure what you mean? The above directives allow for a www subdomain. Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? I'm also assuming the subdirectory is the same name as the domain name (as per your example)?

Comment: And as I mentioned above, make sure you are testing with 302 (temporary) redirects and clear your browser cache.

Comment: https://ghostbin.co/paste/5szmmaj The codes on the link worked, but it does not redirect. When I enter / domainx in domainx.com, it feels like I entered domainx.com. I want to prevent this, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, and is what the code above is supposed to do, but we need to know precisely what the domains/hostnames and subdirectories actually are. (Please edit your question to include this information.) The code you posted is _ghostbin_ is not consistent and I would not expect to work. The code I posted above was based on the format of URLs/hostnames you posted in the question which appeared to show a direct correlation between hostname and subdirectory, but it seems that may not be the case.